How to deal with a modified version of VCL?
We have an old Delphi project (Project1.dpr) that uses packages.
The original Vcl.Grids.pas from Delphi was duplicated and modified. When I try to compile the project, I get this error:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Base1.pas(39): F2051 Unit RSVclHelperFunctions was compiled with a different version of Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid
Base1.pas is part of Project1.dpr
Some of the modified routines in TStringGrid are private.
Vcl.Grids.pas is not the only one. We have 10 more modified files.
What would be the best approach here?
Maybe putting all those 10 files in their own package that I install into the IDE?
In this case I will have to rename TStringGrid to TStringGridX because of course you cannot have two components with the same name.
